# Disable Press <CR> to continue or Q to quit prompt in VxWorks shell

Tags: vxworks

I'm working on a test tool to profile a VxWorks application.  Some of the commands I enter have multiple pages of output and prompt with Press CR to continue, Q to quit on every page.  Is there a way to set the page length so that the commands dump all the output without prompting?

Answer (score 0):

There is no global universal way to disable the paging prompt.

Some functions might have a limited ability to avoid pagination, but others might not.

For example, the "help" strings have a hard pagination of 20 lines.

On the other hand, taskShow takes an optional parameter that can disable paging:

`taskShow(0, 4)` will display information on all tasks without paging, but any value other than 4 as the second argument will result in pagination (and different display operation).

Some of the behavior will depend on the version of vxWorks you are using.